# replace and print with printdocument

Tags: .net, winforms, formatting, richtext, printdocument

i need to replace text in a rich-text box with string.format(rtb.rtf,val1,val2,etc) and print the result with printdocument, but having difficulty

```
Customer:
{0}
Tag:            {1}
Paymethod:      {2}
─────────────────
Status:     {3}
Cash:           {4}
Balance:        {5}
─────────────────
Subtotal:       {6}
─────────────────
VAT:            {7}
Discount:       {8}
═════════════════
Total:      {9}
═════════════════
```

when i look at the rich-text in notepad, i see the bracketed numbers like this
{0}, {1}, etc

I would love your suggestions

Comment: Rich text wouldn't look like that in NotePad.  Show the code you are using to replace the bracketed items.

Comment: this is the richtext, only the words are in plain instead of being bold

Comment: the richtext for the cash line is `Cash:\tab\tab\tab\b0\{6\}\b\par`

Comment: It would be easier if you just loaded the file into a RichTextBox control and work from there.

Comment: i already search how to replace text in the richtextbox without losing formatting, but found none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing a rich text file is fraught with dangers, so I would avoid trying to do it that way.  Simply load the text in a RichTextBox control and replace the text by selecting it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  string findText = "{" + i.ToString() + "}";
  int index = rtb.Text.IndexOf(findText);
  if (index > -1) {
    rtb.Select(index, findText.Length);
    rtb.SelectedText = "new value";
  }
}
```

Comment: can you help with the print issue to, or i should open another question for this

Comment: @Smith That would be a new question.  See [Getting WYSIWYG Print Results from a .NET RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996492.aspx)